# pytest --help does not run when using pytest_configure() in conftest.py

Tags: python, virtualenv, pytest

update the question and subject as I discovered more.
Without conftest.py "pytest --help" returns help content. With the conftest.py "pytest --help" returns this

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 174, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     config._do_configure()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 588, in _do_configure
INTERNALERROR>     self.hook.pytest_configure.call_historic(kwargs=dict(config=self))
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 280, in call_historic
INTERNALERROR>     res = self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 67, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 61, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 76, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/user/git/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 980, in result
INTERNALERROR>     return function(*args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR> TypeError: pytest_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'config'
```

my conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--user", action="store", default="admin", help="user name")
    parser.addoption("--password", action="store", default="password", help="user password")

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def pytest_configure(config):
      import env
      if config.getoption('--user'):
          env.user_name = config.getoption('--user')
```

The conftest.py hasn't been updated for two months but I have a new laptop. Mac High Sierra.

```
Python 3.6.6 . or 3.7.0
pytest version 3.7.1, or 3.7.0
```

Comment: Your `pytest_configure` hook impl misses the `config` argument.

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.config.PytestPluginManager.pytest_configure

Comment: (Thank you) I realize I do have pytest_configure(config) in conftest.py. I updated the post included conftest. I don't know why pytest say it is missing.

Answer (score 9):

Hooks are no fixtures, they are plain functions that `pytest` will find using their exact signatures. So, to fix your issue, just remove `pytest.fixture` decorator from the hook and you're good to go:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    import env
    if config.getoption('--user'):
        env.user_name = config.getoption('--user')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I don't remember why I put a fixture there. I will try to remove it and see if it works. I also found my path messed up. Pytest was calling Python2 even though I was in Python2 virtualenv. Tests are running after fixing that.  Will update after I try.

Comment: Glad I could help! If the question is answered, you can upvote the answer and accept it to mark the question resolved.

Comment: I finally got chance to verify @hoefling 's approach. It works! My co-worker also tried and it worked for him. Unfortunately my stack overflow reputation is not high enough to make the upvote shown.  When I get enough of that I will come back vote again. Thanks again.